# Kotlin + hilt error. [Hilt] and java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, dagger-hilt

I have a problem with my hilt injection. Recently I started learning Kotlin and Hilt for my project. I watched some tutorials and afterwhile tried to write my own code

My build.gradle

```
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.28.3-alpha"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()

    }
}
```

And this one build.gradle

```
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            debuggable true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:23.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:20.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.0.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'

    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.14.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.14.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-dash:2.14.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.14.0'

    // Material Design
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0-alpha02'

    // Architectural Components
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0"

    // Lifecycle
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.2.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.2.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.2.0"

    // Coroutines
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.9'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.9'

    // Coroutine Lifecycle Scopes
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.2.0"

    // Navigation Component
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.0"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.0"

    // Glide
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'

    // Activity KTX for viewModels()
    implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.1.0"

    //Dagger - Hilt
implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.28-alpha"
kapt 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.28-alpha'
implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha02"
kapt 'androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0-alpha02'


}
```

I have a `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)` error
And just one message in console [This one message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYmqZ.png)

Whats wrong? I read a lot of suggestions but none of them helped

[Injection code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRxx2.png)

Comment: > Task :app:kaptDebugKotlin
error: [Hilt]
  android.app.Application, expected to be annotated with @DefineComponent. Found: 
[Hilt]

  [Hilt] Processing did not complete. See error above for details.warning: File for type 'com.spectrum.hetune.data.HetuneApplication_HiltComponents' created in the last round will not be subject to annotation processing.
> Task :app:kaptDebugKotlin FAILED

Answer (score 2):

Did you add *hilt-android-gradle-plugin* to your project's root build.gradle file? This is how my gradle looks like:

```
plugins {
   id 'com.android.application'
   id 'kotlin-android'
   id 'kotlin-kapt'
   id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
   id 'kotlin-parcelize'
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is. But problem still hasnt gone away

Answer (score 2):

just add this

```
hilt {
    enableAggregatingTask = true
}
```

into your build.gradle modules like this

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(path: ":core")
    implementation project(path: ":domain")
    implementation project(path: ":features:homepage")
    implementation project(path: ":features:detailpage")
}

hilt {
    enableAggregatingTask = true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `classpath` version should be the same as these two

```
implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.28-alpha"
kapt 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.28-alpha'
```

If it still doesn't work. Try to update all your hilt related to the lastest version, and make sure change your `kotlin_version` to `1.4.32`. If you want to see the changes on hilt check out this: https://github.com/google/dagger/releases

Answer (score 1):

I just changed my dependency of classpath version same as my hilt version in

**buld.gradle file (Project level)**

like this

**`dependencies {classpath("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.38.1")}`**

Answer (score 1):

Your Class Path Hilt version and Your hilt version are not the same.

> build.gradle(:app)

```
id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android' version '2.44' apply false
```

> build.gradle(Module)

```
def hilt_version="2.44"
implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$hilt_version"
kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:$hilt_version"
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, and solved by updating Dagger Hilt dependencies to the latest version.
You can find the latest version in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android)

Answer (score 0):

i used '1.5.30' instead of '1.7.0' and it worked

id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.5.30' apply false